# Guardar una imagen en python con formato .bmp

Tags: python

Utilizo las librerías

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im
```

Estoy tratando de guardar una imagen en python con el siguiente comando: `fig.savefig('AmplitudDCO_escalado08',dpi=250, format='bmp')` pero me muestra el siguiente error: Format 'bmp' is not supported (supported formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff).

El fragmento del código es:

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=250) # 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
pos1 =ax1.imshow(amplitud_DCO08,cmap='gray')
ax1.title.set_text('Amplitud del DCO')
fig.savefig('AmplitudDCO_escalado08',dpi=250, format='bmp')
```

Es necesario que la imagen este en formato .bmp ya que necesito que quede cuantizada a 8 bits.

Como puedo solucionar este problema? O algún otro método para guardar la imagen en .bmp

Answer (score 2):

Puedes guardar una imagen como `png` y usar la biblioteca de imágenes de Python (PIL) para convertir este archivo a `bmp`, `JPEG`, etc:

```
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.savefig('imagen.png')
Image.open('imagen.png').save('imagen.bmp','bmp')
```

o

```
Image.open('imagen.png').save('imagen.bmp')`
```